# Is there a way to use Git to flag code for future review?

Tags: c#, git, controls, revision

I am currently developing a desktop application in C#.

As I am going through my code, I keep finding other pieces of code that need a second look or can be improved on... but I don't want to derail from my current mission.

Is there a way in Git or Visual Studio that allows me to highlight a block of code for "future review"?

Comment: Add a comment? `// TODO(aaron): Check this later, it looks like the furble could wurfle the qoxbar`

Comment: ^ That's what I was going to suggest. Many modern IDE's have a special syntax highlight and/or search filter specifically for `TODO` items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to flag areas of code are with `TODO`, `FIXME`, etc. comments, as explained in this question: [How do you flag code so that you can come back later and work on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335378/how-do-you-flag-code-so-that-you-can-come-back-later-and-work-on-it)

It looks like these comments show up in the [Task List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/170k1bbs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Visual Studio.

There are also plugins for CI systems to watch for these flagged comments and make sure they don't make it to production. For example the [Task Scanner](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Task+Scanner+Plugin) plugin for Jenkins.

There is nothing in git itself that would help with this problem. The best you could do is store some metadata in the commit message, then write something to watch for the flagged commits.